# Single Activity login flow Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-navigation-graph, android-bottomnav

I am currently working on a school project that displays your timetable, grades, subjects and so on. To use any functionality in the Android application you have to be logged in. Here comes my problem:

When the users starts the application for the first time, they should see a login fragment. Once the login is completed they will be presented with a setup screen where they can choose color themes for grades and other user specific things. Only then should they be presented with the actual main fragment. On the second start the user should directly see the main fragment

The main fragment is a `FragmentContainerView` and a `BottomNavigationBar` that hosts 5 other fragments. In each of those subfragments you can click on items. Then a different fragment should be presented that shows some more details. These fragments however should overlap the bottom navigation so that you have to navigate back before you can choose a different fragment in the bottom navigation bar.

As far as I can tell I need nested `FragmentContainerViews`. The `MainActivity` should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `MainActivity` should host the `LoginFragment`, `SetupFragment` and a `MainFragment`. In the `MainFragment` should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I would like to achieve all of this with a navigation graph. Do I have to use one graph or two for each `FragmentContainerView`? Then there is also the problem with the detail Fragments. If for example I have a `HomeFragment` as a child of the `MainFragment` which is a child of the `MainActivity` and in the `HomeFragment` the user clicks on for example a button to the `SettingsFragment`, this fragment should be displayed as a child of the `MainActivity`. How would I get this working? I've already had a look at this question but don't really understand how to implement it.
[How to setup Multiple nested FragmentContainerViews with respective navigation graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382027/how-to-setup-multiple-nested-fragmentcontainerviews-with-respective-navigation-g)

Could somebody maybe create a very simple implementation of this. I especially need help with the nested `FragmentContainerViews`, the `BottomNavigationBar` and the `NavigationGraph`. I've also come across the problem that the bottom navigation bar doesn't respond anymore.
Thanks for your help in advance. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: This is how it's recommended to set up a login flow: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional The basic use for Navigation is to have a single ``NavHostFragment`` in your main ``Activity`` (which you do) and then that displays the different destinations as you navigate around the app - navigating to your settings page is no different. Whatever you're doing with multiple containers trying to overlay the bottom nav bar... that sounds like you're making things really hard for yourself, and honestly I'd avoid trying to do anything too clever for a school project!

Comment: @cactustictacs I maybe have to clarify my question a bit. It isn't a school project per se. My school has a website which is used for publishing grades and so on. A friend and I got the offer to create an application for that website. The reason why I want to use a nested fragment is, because I don't want that the user can see / interact with the bottom navigation bar before the user is logged in. If there is any other way to achieve that I'm open for ideas.

Comment: I'd just hide/show the bar depending on which fragment is showing - there's an example of how to do it with Navigation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events - you can see glitches sometimes (like the bar changing a moment before the fragment does) but that's an official recommendation, and way easier to work with than multiple fragment containers!

Comment: Great. That will work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1.way

```
val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
val listFragment = ListFragment()
val profileFragment = ProfileFragment()

nav_view.setOnItemSelectedListener {
                when (it) {
                    R.id.homeFragment -> setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
                    R.id.listFragment -> setCurrentFragment(listFragment)
                    R.id.profileFragment -> 
                    setCurrentFragment(profileFragment)
                }
                return@setOnItemSelectedListener
            }



private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main, fragment)
            addToBackStack(null) //If you delete this, press the back button, it will not return to the previous fragment.
            commit()
        }
```

2.way

Navigation with

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DI0NIk-7cz8&t=527s&ab_channel=Stevdza-San